# R : File location and name as argument

Tags: r, function

I have a R script in which I want it to take location and file name  dynamically. Both will be passed as an argument in preceding java code which will call this R script.

```
R Script:

df1 <- read.csv("filename.csv")
vs=colnames(df1)
md=formula(paste(vs[3],"~",vs[1],"+",vs[2]))
fit <- summary(aov(md, data=df1))[[1]]
```

Also there will be unique ID in java code which has to be the name of two output files.

Is there any way in R to use these arguments and take the file name, location and unique ID dynamically.

Tha java code which call this Rscript is:

```
buildCommand.add("Rscript  ");  
buildCommand.add(scriptName);
buildCommand.add(inputFileWithPathExtension);
buildCommand.add(uniqueIdForR);
```

I have to use `uniqueuniqueIdForR` for naming two output files and `inputFileWithPathExtension` for reading input file in R.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It will probably be helpful for people wanting to answer to know the details of how your Java code is calling the R script, because how you pass arguments to R will depend on the mechanics of that.

Comment: If you are calling this script via `Rscript`, take a look at `?commandArgs` for reading command line parameters in R.

Comment: @joran I have edited my question, kindly look at it.